# How to listen to user touches for UICollectionViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have implemented a `UICollectionView` that holds list of UIImageView objects.

I want the user to be taken to YouTube with specific URL when he touched an image.

But I don't know how to add touch listener for each **UICollectionViewCell**:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell: PhotoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PhotoCell
    cell.loadImage(thumbnailFileURLs[indexPath.row], originalImagePath: originalFileURLs[indexPath.row])

    return cell
    }
```

My PhotoCell class has a member variable that holds the URL to youtube.

For each PhotoCell object, when pressed, I want my app to send the user to youtube.com website or APP (if installed)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol method `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)`. When you press one of your collection view cells this method get called. Here is sample implementation

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let url = thumbnailFileURLS[indexPath.item]
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

By the way I don't know where you get url. So I improvised a bit :)

Comment: By the way, what is the difference between indexPath.item and indexPath.row

Comment: There is no difference. It is semantic. When you deal with `UITableView`s you say "row" and when you deal with `UICollectionView`s yo say "item"

Comment: Does this go in the viewDidLoad()

Comment: @tccpg288 No, it goes below viewDidLoad() as a separate function in the view controller

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

didSelectItemAtIndexPath has been renamed to didSelectItemAt in Swift 5

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         //Do your logic here

    }
```